# How to print previous month in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to display only previous **month** not with the days and year using PowerShell. I can get the desired result using "(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)" But this command giving me the complete date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

`(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month`

Which gets you the month number, which, for example, would be `10` for `October`, if it were currently `November`.

If you want the month name, you can use:

`[CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month)`

Which, for month 10, would give:

`October`

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close with what you had! Just need one more parameter:

```
(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month;
```

In this case we get a return of 10.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say if you want the previous month number, name or short name, so here they each are:

```
(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month
(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month)
(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just send to month name to string and format it how you like..
for the month name its:

```
(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("MMMM")
```